# Formatting Date of a collection in an Anonymous Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I got a business layer which returns an anonymous object which has a collection of rows which have dates.  I want to get regional formatting of the dates, but I don't want to pass the regional setting into the business layer, instead keeping the formatting in the Controller Action of the MVC website.

Biz Layer:

```
public object GetItems(int catID)
{
 var data = GetDbItems(catId).ToList();
 var Items = new 
         {
            total = data.Count(),
            page = 1,
            rows = (from c in data
                    select new {
                       ID = c.id,
                       Desc = c.desc,
                       CreationDate = c.CreationDate
                    })
         };

 return Items;
}
```

back in the Action Method of the controller I want to format the date in the collection inside of the anonymous type.  How can I do this?

```
public JsonResult GetItems(int catID)
{
 string cultureString = HttpContext.Request.UserLanguages.FirstOrDefault();
 DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureString).DateTimeFormat;
 var items = bizLayer.GetItems(catID);
 var test = from i in items
       select i.rows;  // ????  doesn't know about this collection yet.
 }
```

What I want to do.

get at the rows collection of the anonymous type, find the date column and format it with

```
CreateDate = c.CreateDate.ToString("d", dtfi)
```

Comment: Business layers returning anonymous objects is a bad idea, using strong typed models will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies, I don't know which answer to vote.  I am clear now that the codebase I inherited has a blurry SoC. I needed to do a quick fix but now looks like there is alot more work to make things better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I got a business layer which returns an anonymous object

That's probably the first thing that needs to be fixed and replace this anonymous object by a strongly typed model which would greatly simplify the mapping of this domain model to a view model in order to perform the desired formatting.

Comment: isn't there a way to unbox an anonymous method using the dynamic keyword or using some sort of Cast as per:                             http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/01/09/horrible-grotty-hack-returning-an-anonymous-type-instance.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You need to make a concrete class with the same properties as your anonymous object(s) and pass back a `YourNewClass` instead of an `object`.

Answer (score 0):

Why the business layer returns an anonymous object is certainly vague, you should fix that first. But if you can't the best shot you've got is parsing each element as a DateTime; and then reusing that information for the rest of the rows.

Comment: how would I parse each element as a DateTime in the Controller Action layer.